# Excel is changing the digits after 15th to "0". Please suggest what to do in the same case

Tags: java

In the application, we are Exporting the data to Excel and saving it. Post opening the file, there is a column "Reference Number" which of 16 digits and it is displayed in exponential form.

After converting it into Number from Format Cells, it is changing it in Number Format but 16th digit is converted to "0". I tried to change it in text Format also but it is again converting it into exponential Form.

I tried to convert in number, text , customized form, etc. But Nothing is working. Please Suggest as I want the 16 digit Reference Number.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because you are asking us about a bug without showing us code.  Without concrete code, we can only guess what the problem might be, which is not useful to you or future readers.  If you can [edit] your question to show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem, this downvote may be retracted.

Comment: Not exactly a solution, but my guess is that if you prepend the 16-digit number with a string "instead of just 1234567890123456, you output ref=1234567890123456" you will see it properly in Excel. Excel is probably automatically inferring a number type for the cell before you try to convert it to text...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numbers in Excel are stored a double precision (64-bit) floating point numbers.  These have between 15 and 16 digits of precision.  If you need numbers of that length or longer to be stored exactly, you must store them as text.

Comment: Agreed that they are stored in Double Precision format but I am not storing them. I am Exporting the File and the file is getting saved in .xls format and once we open it we find the digit in Exponential form of that particular column.

Comment: You haven't told us how you're "exporting" the data.  CSV? If so, put the numbers in double quotes to make them text.

Comment: While exporting the data, it is in ".xls" format only. It is not in .csv or .txt format

Comment: Again, YOU HAVE NOT EXPLAINED HOW YOU ARE EXPORTING THE DATA.  Assuming you're using something like POI, you will have to set the cell format to text instead of numeric.  If you want more detailed help please edit your post to explain how you are generating the .xls file and INCLUDE YOUR CODE.

Comment: In Application,there is a button "export to Excel" which is taking the values stored in a table in which the "Reference Number" column is stored as String(Data type) so it is getting saved/downloaded in .xls format.After opening the file that is saved on the system we can see that in exponential Format Like <af:activeCommandToolbarButton text="#{rbScanReject.LBL_Export_Excel}"
                                               immediate="true" visible="true"
                                               id="actb1"
                                               icon="/images/xlsfile_ena.png">

Comment: I guess I got the solution of that question. I have changed that to text and somehow it was working for me. But the other issue is if I am changing any number to text, I won't be able to do any operations on that figure like addition or something.

Comment: If you think this question would be helpful for others please hit vote button to vote the question.